# Use of majority to refer to quantity

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to use 'majority' to refer to quantity?  For example: More than half the garbage in our city is recycled . The majority of garbage is recycled.

If this is incorrect, why?

Comment: I often hear this and it always grates - I agree will @Bill Franke. The antonym of _majority_ is _minority_ but I've never heard anyone say _The minority of garbage is not recycled._

Answer (score 9):

This word should probably be used only for countable items rather than non-countable collective nouns like "garbage", but it falls into the same category as "[**amount**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/amount)" versus "**the number of**" when talking about countable things like *people* and *complaints*: "INFORMAL a number of things. Many people consider this use to be incorrect:

> *The call centre handles a huge **amount** of complaints every day.*"

The proper way to say this is:

> *The call centre handles a huge **number** of complaints every day.*

The sentence you ask about should probably be:

> **Most of the** garbage is recycled.

Comment: But you can weigh or measure garbage, thereby putting "majority" into context. (*I have five pounds of garbage. The majority of it (four pounds) comes from leftover meals.*)

Answer (score 3):

It's safer to stick to countable things when using *majority* (see Bill Franke's answer), but I don't think it's incorrect to use it the way you're proposing.  From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majority):

> **3 a :** a number or percentage equaling more than half of a total <a *majority* of voters> <a two-thirds *majority*>
>   **b :** the excess of a majority over the remainder of the total : margin <won by a *majority* of 10 votes>
>   **c :** the greater quantity or share <the *majority* of the time>

Notice the example given for sense 3c, which clearly applies to an uncountable quantity. There are probably some things (like time) which are more customary for use with *majority*, and will perhaps grate less on finicky ears.

Comment: OED <http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/majority?q=majority> has a footnote "Strictly speaking, **majority** should be used with countable nouns to mean ‘the greater number’, as in *the majority of cases*. Use with uncountable nouns to mean ‘the greatest part’, as in *I spent the majority of the day reading*, is not considered good standard English, although it is common in informal contexts."

Comment: Bad standard English?

Comment: Answers very helpful.  Much appreciated.