# Correct use of 'majority'

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

I believe *majority* is correctly used with a plural noun — "majority of people" or "majority of voters". It's becoming used frequently with a singular noun — "majority of work" or "majority of travel". Is this incorrect use of *majority*?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113731/use-of-majority-to-refer-to-quantity

Answer (score 5):

You should note that *work* and *travel* are mass nouns here; you can't pluralize them. Whether or not it's correct to use *majority* with a singular mass noun, it's not a new usage: from the OED, there was a similar use in 1882: *"The majority of the coral which I collected ... was obtained by divers."*

Whether it's acceptable to use *majority* with a singular count noun is a different question. This may depend on the noun. I personally have no problem with using it for a collective noun, such as *"the majority of the audience"*, but a sentence like *"the majority of his farm is planted with cotton"* sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Garner in _Modern American Usage_ (p522) would agree with you. He recommends: "When _most_ will suffice, use it in place of _majority_."

Comment: It seems like as soon as you use *majority* with an otherwise singular noun, it immediately forces the noun to be decomposed into its constituent elements:  *The majority of this penny is actually Zinc.*  And in your case *a farm* gets decomposed into *acres*