# Is 'the majority of' singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, premodifiers

I have the following question:

> The majority of fund studies **has or have** agreed that a common attribute for superior performance is due to managers' skill.

Comment: "The majority of" is usually used to modify a following noun. The main verb of the sentence agrees with *that* noun. Here, that noun is the plural "studies," so you should use the plural verb form "have."

Comment: It's likely that you do not intend to convey that there is an unstated attribute that is a good predictor of superior performance and that attribute comes into being because of manager skill.  Rather I think you mean that a variable present in a significant portion of the group exhibiting superior performance ***is*** highly skilled managers.

Answer (score 16):

Like the words *some* and *most*, a premodifying phrase like *the majority of* is in and of itself ***neither*** singular ***nor*** plural.  It has no number.

The noun it is modifying continues to function as the subject for purposes of agreement with the verb.   This allows then for both possibilities:

1. (The majority of) the **water is** safe to drink.
2. (The majority of) the **bottles are** safe to drink.

Notice how adding *the majority of* doesn’t change anything in those two examples.

Therefore because *studies* is plural, so too is *the majority of studies*:

> The majority of fund **studies have** agreed that a common attribute for superior performance is due to managers’ skill.

That’s because it just means *most fund studies*; the number does not change.

Comment: Clearly what happens when applied to a singular noun is _not a lot_…

Comment: I was always taught that 'majority' can only be used with countable nouns. How, then, can you have 'the majority of the water'?

Comment: @Mynamite Easily: *“The majority of the water was drunk in the first two days of our trip.”*  It just means most of it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. 'Water' is not a countable noun. How about 'The majority of the table was covered with books', would you consider that correct?

Comment: @Mynamite Yes, certainly that is just fine.

Comment: Can you quote an authority for that? I'm afraid I disagree, and so do several other people on this site [link1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133169/correct-use-of-majority), [link2](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113731/use-of-majority-to-refer-to-quantity)

Comment: @Mynamite I don’t understand what you mean by “authority”. I also don’t understand why you think that *majority* means something other than “the major part of” something — that is, most of it.  It’s completely grammatical and I have never in all my life heard anything suggest that it might not be.

Comment: "Majority" means "greatest number" so "the majority of water" does not make sense.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, "majority" often is understood to mean "more than half" specifically, not just "the greatest number of", which is why the word [plurality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality_(voting)) is used by some people to refer to a greatest number that is not more than half of the whole. If "majority" is understood as meaning "more than half," "the majority of the water" makes sense.

Comment: @sumelic it is also unnecessarily verbose: we usually say "most water", whereas "the majority of the water" is very poor use of English. "Majority" is usually a head count. Have a look at the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/majority) examples. They are all about people.

Comment: @sumelic to say "the majority of the water is safe to drink" can mean that barely half of the water is safe - so actually not very safe at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're wrong that majority can only mean the greatest number. It can also mean the greater part, as in the majority of the power or the majority of the information. It is not restricted to use on count nouns only. This is trivially documented in any corpus you bother examining; I recommend you do so. I also recommend you ask a new question instead of bickering in comments.

Comment: "*Strictly speaking, 'majority' should be used with countable nouns to mean ‘the greater number’, as in 'the majority of cases'. Use with uncountable nouns to mean ‘the greatest part’, as in 'I spent the majority of the day reading', is not considered good standard English, although it is common in informal contexts*", says [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/majority).

Comment: @Joachim I wish you good fortune in the wars to come as you struggle to convince native speakers that [they have to stop spending ***the majority of their time***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/majority-of-singular-noncount-nouns-usage-minority) doing whatever it is they're doing.  :)

Comment: @tchrist Oh no, I don't feel the urge to convince anyone as that meaning is obvious :) I just looked into it, as I have used it exclusively for countable nouns (it's like that in Dutch, and a singular verb is always used), and this snippet from Lexico seemed to neatly summarize what the discussion here was about.

Answer (score 0):

For US English users who often look to Merriam-Webster Dictionary as a reference, this is a very helpful resource: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/majority-of-singular-noncount-nouns-usage-minority

Their conclusion:

> The question then arises: do majority and minority take a singular or plural verb? The answer is most often determined, again, by the countability of the noun being apportioned: A majority of the voters are in favor of the law. The majority of the wine is from Argentina. A majority of the songs feature her on guitar. A majority of my day is devoted to keeping records. A majority of my work hours are devoted to keeping records. A majority of the workforce is categorized as blue-collar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to agree with those who believe that in some of the examples, majority was used when most would have been more correct.  Ergo, it really depends on how one defines majority.

From my perspective, majority would be a 'greater' part/amount (say, 53/47) - as opposed to most that, again from my perspective, would signify a much greater numerical difference, viz 70/30.

Again, just my opinion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425603)