# The correct synonym for the majority of them

Tags: grammar

what is the correct synonym for "the majority of them"?

Is the greatest number of them? It sounds very strangely.

More details please see:

[Is 'the majority of' singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273893/is-the-majority-of-singular-or-plural)

> "Majority" means "greatest number" so "the majority of water" does not
> make sense.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with _the majority of them_. And there's no such thing as "the correct synonym for" anything.

Comment: Commonly, folks say *most of them*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it sounds strange is that it should be *“the greater number of them.”* Traditionally, superlatives like *greatest* are used when comparing three or more things, and comparatives like *greater* are used when comparing two things. Here, you are presumably comparing the ones who are with the ones who aren't, so *greater* is the proper word to use.

This “rule” is obeyed less today than it was during the 19th century, but some people still follow it. And maybe you should think of “*the greater number of them*” as a frozen form, where *greater* is more idiomatic than *greatest*.

See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&content=greater+number+of+them%2C+greatest+number+of+them&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreater%20number%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20number%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: how about "most of them"?

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be a binary comparison. If you have an election with four candidates in which A gets 51% of the vote, B gets 30%, C gets 18% and D gets 1% then the greatest number of them voted for A.

Comment: @BoldBen: [nitpicking] but then it's not a synonym for *majority*. A could have the greatest number with just 30% of the vote.

Comment: So you would say that "the majority" is always contrasted with "the minority" who are all those who do not meet the criteria for inclusion in "the majority"? For example "the majority of humans have brown eyes" groups all those with blue, grey, green, hazel and pink eyes into the minority. That's certainly a valid point of view.

Comment: @BoldBen: *The majority* means more than 50%.  *The greater number* also (I believe) means more than 50%. So they're synonyms in that sense. *Most of the* means substantially more than 50%.

Answer (score 0):

The majority is one half of the population plus one. That might be referred to as the *Bare* majority, as in just barely a majority. If everyone of them except a few then it would be an *Overwhelming* majority.

"Greatest number of them? It sounds very strangely" does indeed sound very strangely since it should be the *Largest number* of them. It may or may not sound *Strange*. Strangely is an adverb, modifying a verb.